# javascript in html form input

Tags: javascript, html

I want the javascript to show the data in the field, but this is not working.

I tried the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="skin" value="&skin=
<script type="text/javascript">document.write((get()));</script>
">
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using `document.write()`, which I wouldn't usually recommend, you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="skin" value="&skin=' + get() + '">');
</script>
```

(The problem with your code may have been extra whitespace introduced by including the script element on its own line, though you don't actually explain what the problem is so I'm just guessing.)

Alternatively you can include the element in your HTML without a value and then update it after it is parsed, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="skin" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByName("skin")[0].value = "&skin=" + get();
</script>
```

Note that `getElementsByName` returns a list of all elements with the specified name, so the second answer assumes you want to change the *first* (or only) element with `name="skin"`. Instead I'd recommend you give it a unique ID and use:

```
document.getElementById("theNewUniqueId").value = "&skin=" + get();
```

Both ways assume that `get()` is defined earlier on your page.

**Better to do it server-side though.**

Comment: You're welcome. When you're happy with one of the answers you receive you should accept it (click the big tick next to it - it should turn green).

Answer (score 0):

You're improperly using Javascript here. You should instead use PHP, and write code that looks similar to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="skin" value="&skin=<?= $_GET["skin"] ?>">
```

or you should instead set the value in Javascript.

```
var input = getElementById("INPUT_ID");
input.value = "$skin=" + some_string_variable;
```

Comment: "You should instead use PHP" _or whichever server-side technology applies in your environment_.